# Git mistake or misunderstanding

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'am starting working with Git. So I have a NAS server where I've installed Git server. I've initalized a git projet like this on my nas

> git --bare init my_project

After thaht i've cloned this project on my working computer like this

> git clone ssh://user@ip_nas_server/path_to_my_project

It's working I have an empty git project on my computer after that I init `git flow` like this, with all default parameters

> git flow init

So now I add a new file in my project on my computer. I open `SourceTree` so I can see `develop` and `master` branch, and I see my new file I added it and I commit it, everything works.
After thaht I try to pushed and here I have a problem, when I push with sourcetree everything works `SourceTree` return me succes but if I go on my NAS server in my project directory I can't see any new file and I don't understand why, should I do something else to update project on my NAS?

Log return after pushed from `sourcetree`, I think this i strange to have the same path in `Pushing to` and `To`

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags 
origin develop:develop
Pushing to ssh://path_to_nas_project
To ssh://path_to_nas_project
4b92533..05ea6c2  develop -> develop
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/develop'

Finished with succes
```

Comment: ‘_but if I go on my NAS server in my project directory I can't see any new file_’ Do you know what a _bare_ repository is?

Comment: @Biffen AH nice so this is normal if I don't see any files in my nas repositorie, I nedd to clone nas repositorie in other computer for example and here I'll see my files ma I right?

Comment: Yes. Or the same computer. Or simply not use a bare repository in the first place.

Comment: *Or simply not use a bare repository* Don't follow this advice. A non-bare repository on the server (NAS) comes with a lot of trouble. Use a bare repository.